# Angular 2 rc.4 recommended UI

Tags: angular, material-design

I'm relatively new to Angular, so I'm learning Angular 2 using rc.4. Is there a recommended set of UI components that will work with this version? I tried using Angular Material, but "npm install" with the necessary items in my package.json file reports that Angular Material is looking for Angular versions earlier than rc.4. In fact most of the UI component libraries I've looked at seem to only work with earlier releases of Angular 2.

Does anyone have any suggestions, pointers, ideas?

Comment: primeng will be compatible with rc4 on mid-july. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/

Comment: @Sergio Nice. What's the source of that info?

Comment: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3978 "_beta-10 is scheduled in 3 weeks_", you can consider the statement as _oficial_

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll keep an eye open for it. I'm also looking forward to angular-material to catch up with the latest release candidate.